# Deploying lambdas effectively (only deploy those that changed) with Terraform/CloudFormation/Something else

Tags: lambda, continuous-integration, aws-cloudformation, terraform

So far, I have been using CloudFormation to deploy my lambdas. I find this process very slow and inefficient tho - eg. it may take minutes but it should have taken just seconds if its just deploying that 1 function? Most functions would not have changed but I believe CloudFormation does not differentiate and will deploy everything anyway. Is there a way I can do it more effectively? Like check what has changed and only deploy the changes?

Another benefit is I can have less versions perhaps?

Comment: Did you try running it though a CI such as Jenkins and checking if any commits were made?

Comment: @BeshoyHanna, but usually CI is triggered by new commits, in my opinion that is insufficient because the new commit may only change 1 function for example. Or maybe the CI deploys both infra and code. Sometimes only infra changes (eg. terraform/CloudFormation) so I should not need to deploy my code

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right, but I was alluding to maybe having sepreate repos for each function?

Comment: @BeshoyHanna, but that will mean a ton on repos :(

Comment: @Jiew Meng Can you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `source_code_hash` of the `aws_lambda_function` resource to have Terraform check if the Lambda function has changed. If nothing has changed then it won't upload a new version and your plan will show no changes to be made.

This is given as an [example in the docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html#example-usage):

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  filename         = "lambda_function_payload.zip"
  function_name    = "lambda_function_name"
  role             = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn}"
  handler          = "exports.test"
  source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("lambda_function_payload.zip"))}"
  runtime          = "nodejs8.10"

  environment {
    variables = {
      foo = "bar"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing it correct, but I notice that even when the source code has is changed and I do `terraform apply`, the new source code does not get applied. It seems as if terraform updates the last update time and hash but not upload the new zip?

Comment: It might be worth editing your question to show what you've tried and the steps you follow to try to get Terraform to update the Lambda function code. Looking at the source code for the `aws_lambda_function` resource, it fetches the function package hash from AWS and is independently checking that against the `source_code_hash` provided so it shouldn't be possible for Terraform to be ignoring the changes to the package and just updating its own state file.

Comment: If you use a versioned lambda function, you need to set `publish = true` on the `aws_lambda_function` resource. https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html#publish

Answer (score 3):

I created [this](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/rojopolis/lambda-python-archive/aws/0.1.4) Terraform module to address exactly this issue.  Even setting the source_code_hash isn't sufficient because when zips are made they typically include some filesystem metadata.  With my module the hash should be stable (only change when the source changes).  The module is specific to Python, but the hash stability could be applied to any runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I use the aws cli in the gitlab pipeline to deploy and update my lambdas on commit.

I zip the content. Upload it to S3 and trigger an function update with the new artifact on S3.

This is way faster than running a Cloud Formation template:

```
# Filename
FILENAME="${ARTIFACT_ID}-${version}-$BUILD_NUMBER.zip"
zip -r -D $FILENAME ./*
# Copy the bundle to s3
aws s3 cp $FILENAME "s3://$S3_BUCKET/$FILENAME"
# Trigger update of lambda function
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --s3-key $FILENAME
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try https://serverless.com. Easy for lambda function deployment and also you can create other resources like dynamodb or s3 buckets with couple of lines.

1) Create serverless project.

```
serverless create --template aws-nodejs --path my-service
```

2) write your function login in handler.js file and deploy.

```
serverless deploy
```

3) you can create multiple functions in one service. Also, you have the option to deploy only one function.

```
serverless deploy // for all the functions in one service
serverless deploy function -f functionName //deploy function with name 'functionName'
```

You can watch logs from the terminal too, serverless framework also has plugins support e.g. you can write your source code in typescript and serverless plugin for typescript will do the rest itself.
I have been using serverless for quite a while now, and this is far the best solution I found for continuous integration. Worth a try.